# Dual booting Ubuntu with Windows - increasing partition space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 10.
Being an unexperienced user I installed my Ubuntu on my C:/ partition, which has relatively little space and I don't seem to have access to my D:/ partition.
Is there any way I can use my D:/ disk space without having to uninstall Ubuntu and reinstall it on D:/?

Also if anyone could explain how the whole partitioning method works with Ubuntu that'll be wonderful.

Thanks!

Comment: Um... If you put Ubuntu on C:/, that means you've overwritten Windows...

Answer (score 0):

This will work for most cases:

1. Open the program Disks
2. Find the hard drive and partition that correspond to your D: drive
3. Press the play button
4. Disks will tell you where it has been mounted under "Contents". Click the link to go there.

More advanced configuration is possible. Just ask.